# Eclipse Plugin: Opening A New Window From The WorkBench

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am new in developing Eclipse plugin and i have manage to do a lot of work. This is where i have got stuck. I have a view with a button. When a user cklicks on the button i want  a new window to be opened(The window is a form with Text areas, buttons and other SWT widgets). I have finished creating the window.

After I compile the application, I get a new instance of the eclipse workbench(as expected) but when I open the view and clicks on the button, the window don't show up. This is the window code snippet:

```
public class NewWindow {
    private Display display;
    private Shell shell;

    public NewWindow(){

        this.display = new Display();
    shell = new Shell(displaySWT.TITLE | SWT.MIN | SWT.CLOSE);
    shell.setText("fffffffffffff");

              // additional code here
               ...
               ...

    shell.open();
    this.shellSleep();  // this methode is implemented in my code
}
```

This is the code snippet that calls this class:

...
...

```
this.btnCreateNewQuery.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener(){
            public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e){

            }
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e){                                   NewWindow b = new NewWindow();

        }
    });
```

...
...

I don't understand why the window don't show up. I have tried to fix it but has not find anything yet.  I read something on this site but i don't understand what they meant. this is the link: 
[How do I get the workbench window to open a modal dialog in an Eclipse based project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443245/how-do-i-get-the-workbench-window-to-open-a-modal-dialog-in-an-eclipse-based-proj)

Answer (score 4):

Eddy, thats pretty easy to solve. Just do not create a new Display. Reuse the one from the workbench:

```
public NewWindow() {
        this.display = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay();
        shell = new Shell(display, SWT.TITLE | SWT.MIN | SWT.CLOSE);
        shell.setText("fffffffffffff");

              // additional code here
               ...
               ...

        shell.open();
        this.shellSleep();  // this methode is implemented in my code
}
```

Alternativly you can dismiss the display variable and just pass null to the Shell constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to create a new Shell.  Instead pass the parent Shell into your new class.  I find it easier to extend one of the Dialog classes (or Dialog itself) for new windows.  Then in your constructor you can call super(Shell parent) to initialize all the environment/GUI stuff for you and then you can layout the Dialog area the way you want.  Then to open the new window you do a dialog.open().

Comment: I cannot understand the above statement. Can you please elaborate on it, with a code snippet probably